# FastAPI: Is there a way to use an HTML form to act as the path parameters for an endpoint?

Tags: html, fastapi

I have a `GET` function written to grab a file from an endpoint given namespace and project parameters. It looks a little something like this:

```
@app.get('/{namespace}/{project}')
async def get_project(namespace, project):
    # this then uses the response module...
```

I want submitted content of my HTML form to become the `{namespace}` and `{project}` values, but I can't find a way to do so. So far, my code looks like this:

```
<form action="/{namespace}/{project}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Is there any way to do this with just HTML and FastAPI?

Comment: No, don't use path parameters for parameters you expect a user to provide. In this case you'll probably want to use regular GET parameters instead.

Comment: What do you mean by regular GET parameters? What might that look like?

Comment: `@app.get('/files')`, `get_project(namespace, project)`, call as `/files?namespace=..&project=...`; However, usually you have the available files as a list and create a set of URLs that point to each file, instead of letting the user type in free text for what they want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive it in the post method.
Why are you using the GET method?
And if you need to use GET method, you can you

```
<a herf="/{namespace}/{project}"> </a>
```

I hope it will help you to solve this issue.

Comment: How could I go about receiving it using POST? I'm also not sure what the `<a>` tag will do, since it'll be going to the URL string and not actually substituting values in for `namespace` and `project`.

Comment: Therefore, you can use the POST method. That will be best for you.

Comment: I am talling you to use POST method on your 
@app.post('/{namespace}/{project}')
async def get_project(namespace, project):